# types for the response data of a get

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I am migrating a NodeJS project from javascript to typescript.
So, I am trying to add types.

The only problem that I have left, are issues with the types for dynamodb queries.

```
  static async hasUser(user: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const params = {
      TableName: "users",
      Key: { user }
    };

    const data = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      docClient.get(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(data);
        }
      });
    }).catch((_err) => false);

    if (!data) return false;
    const user = data.Item;            <<----- problem is here.
    return user != null;    
  }
```

When AWS dynamodb performs a `get(...)`, there actually always is an `Item` property on the return value. However, I don't know which type I should use here to depict it.

I have the `aws-sdk` dependency already in place.
(And from what I read, the `@types/aws-sdk` dependency is no longer necessary because the types are supposed to be included inside the `aws-sdk` dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Considering to rewrite it like this:

```
try {
  const data: DocumentClient.GetItemOutput = await promisify((cb) => (docClient.get(params, cb)))()
  return data && data.Item != null;
} catch( err ) {
  return false;
}
```

Not 100% sure if the type `GetItemOutput` is correct.
But it seems to match for now.